# Counting binary substrings

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

The exercise i am working on requires me to read a binary sequence stored in a text file. The objective is to find the occurrences of all subsequences of length between a and b (their values are given in the function parameters) and put them in a list of tuples.

For example: If the following binary sequence is given as input and the length of each subsequence should be between 2 and 4:

```
a = 2 
b = 4 

01010010010001000111101100001010011001111000010010011110010000000
```

I should write a program to generate the following output:

```
[(1, ["1011", "1101"]), 
 (2, ["0101", "0110", "1010"]), 
 (3, ["0111", "101", "1110", "1111"]), 
 (4, ["0001", "0011", "1100"]), 
 (5, ["011", "1000", "110"]), 
 (6, ["0000", "111"]), 
 (7, ["0010", "1001"]), 
 (8, ["0100"]), 
 (10, ["010"]), 
 (11, ["000", "001", "11"]), 
 (12, ["100"]),            
 (15, ["01", "10"]), 
 (23, ["00"] )]
```

You will notice that each tuple in the list has two elements. The first element is the number of times a subsequence appears in the given sequence whilst the second element is the list containing the corresponding subsequences.

E.g. the first tuple indicates that the subsequences "1011" and "1101" appear only once in the given sequence.

The solution i have written does solve the problem (it passes all correctness tests), but it is slow and doesn't pass the performance tests (it only passes 5 out of 22 tests) in which the maximum timeout is set to 1 second. How could i make this solution faster?

I am not allowed to import any <strike>external</strike> libraries.

```
def ex1(ftesto,a,b,n):
    with open(ftesto,encoding='utf8') as f: 
        S = f.read().replace('\n','')
    N = len(S)
    D = {} 
    subsequences = {} 
    for i in range(N+1):
        for j in range(i+1,N+1): 
            if a <= len(S[i:j]) <= b: 
                if S[i:j] not in D:
                    D[S[i:j]] = 1   
                else:
                    D[S[i:j]] += 1                     
    for k,v in D.items(): 
        subsequences.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)
    result = sorted([(k,sorted(v)) for k,v in subsequences.items()])   
    return result[:n] 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
   ftesto = 'ft1.txt'
   a = 2
   b = 4
   n = 20
```

The amount of elements in the list must be equal or less than "n". That explains why i am using the slicing at the end of the function.

Comment: from which range are the values a, b, n and the length of the 01-string

Comment: read the post please

Comment: so a=2, b=4 and the string is 01010010010001000111101100001010011001111000010010011110010000000 and this takes more than one second to calculate the result?

Comment: @miracle173 It takes much longer time if a very long sequence is given as input. That's why i need to improve efficiency

Comment: that's why I want to know how long the sequence can be

Answer (score 3):

## PEP 8

You are violating several [Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/) rules:

- commas should be followed by a space,
- variables should be `snake_case`,
- always surround binary operators with one space

## Never called

`ex1()` is never called by your mainline.

## Declare variables closer to where they are used

`subsequences` is declared 7 lines earlier than it needs to be.

## Separate I/O from processing

`ex1()` cannot be called with test data, unless that test data is in a file.  Use two functions.  One that solves the problem with an in-memory string, and a second that reads the string from a file for processing.

## Avoid `dict.setdefault(...)`

`subsequences.setdefault(v, []).append(k)` will create a new list (`[]`) every time it is executed.  Many times this default will never be used, and must be garbage collected.  This is just wasting time.

Instead, use `collections.defaultdict`.  Note that `collections` is not an external library; it is internal, built into Python.

## Counter

Similarly, use `collections.Counter` for counting objects.  Again, built into Python; not an external library.

## Reworked Code

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def binary_sequence_counts(sequence, shortest, longest, limit):
    n = len(sequence)

    sequence_counter = Counter()
    for i in range(n + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
            if shortest <= len(sequence[i:j]) <= longest:
                sequence_counter[sequence[i:j]] += 1

    subsequences = defaultdict(list)
    for subsequence, count in sequence_counter.items():
        subsequences[count].append(subsequence)

    result = sorted((count, sorted(subseqs)) for count, subseqs in subsequences.items())
    return result[:limit]

def ex1(ftesto, a, b, n):
    with open(ftesto, encoding='utf8') as f:
        sequence = f.read().replace('\n', '')

    return binary_sequence_counts(sequence, a, b, n)

def testcase():
    seq = "01010010010001000111101100001010011001111000010010011110010000000"
    result = binary_sequence_counts(seq, 2, 4, 20)
    # print result, or
    # check if result is correct
```

The above code is way more readable than the original.

## Efficiency

This code is just plain awful:

```py
    for i in range(n + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
            if shortest <= len(sequence[i:j]) <= longest:
                ...
```

If your sequence is 100,000 digits long, the inner loop will execute about 5,000,000,000 times!  That's a lot!  Especially if you're only concerned with subsequences between 2 and 4 digits long, in which case you only need about 300,000 iterations.

A simple modification of the `range(...)` limits would dramatically improve your speed.  If you do it correctly, you can even get rid of the `a <= len(...) <= b` test, because with the correct ranges you will not be able to generate sequences that are the incorrect length.

In fact, with the correct limits, you could even use the counter to do the counting entirely for you:

```py
sequence_counts = Counter(sequence[i:j]
                          for i in range(...)
                          for j in range(...))
```

Proper range limits left as exercise to student.

## min heap

You are sorting a potentially huge list of values, and then returning only the n-smallest results.  `sorted(iterable)[:n]`  This can be a potentially huge waste of time!

Using the `heapq.nsmallest(n, iterable)` (again, built-in, not an external library), you can reduce the amount of space used, and possibly the amount of time.  Note that this is faster only for smaller values of `n`.  If `n` is big, it can be faster to use `sorted(iterable)[:n]`.  Always profile!

## Roll Your Own

The question has been updated to disallow any imports.  No problem.  We'll just have to implement our own `defaultdict` and `Counter`.
Assuming your are allowed to create your own `class` ...

### `object.__missing__`

When a `dict.__getitem__` is called, but the dictionary does not contain that key, [`object.__missing__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__missing__#object.__missing__) is called.  We can use this method to change the behaviour.

### Counter

To implement a simple "counter" dictionary, we just need `0` to be returned for any missing key.

```py
class Counter(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0
```

If the key is missing, `0` is returned.  If you "add 1" to a missing key, `0` is returned, `1` is added to the returned value, and the resulting `1` is stored back under that key:

```py
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c['foo']
0
>>> c['bar'] += 1
>>> c['bar'] += 1
>>> c
{'bar': 2}
```

Notice that the `'foo'` key still does not exist; only the `'bar'` key exists because values were actually written to it.

### defaultdict

You don't actually need a full `defaultdict` here.  You just need a dictionary which returns an empty list when an unknown key is retrieved.  Unlike the `Counter` class above, we need to remember the list that was returned for the key, because we'll be appending items to the list, which (unlike the `+=` operator) won't write the result back into the dictionary.

```py
class DictOfLists(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = []
        return self[key]
```

Unlike the `Counter`, referencing an unknown key will create the key in the dictionary, filling it with an empty list:

```py
>>> dol = DictOfLists()
>>> dol['foo']
[]
>>> dol['bar'].append("baz")
>>> dol
{'foo': [], 'bar': ['baz']}
>>>
```

The actual `defaultdict` allows you to specify a factory function in the constructor, to create values for the missing keys.  That isn't too much more complicated.  Feel free to research this.

Comment: i really appreciate your answer. I am sorry. I just realized i made a mistake in the description of the exercise. The college teacher has forbidden us to use any libraries which means that we are not even allowed to type import in our code. Hence, the task becomes more difficult.

The idea of limiting the range sounds very good. I will try it

Comment: You changed "_not allowed to import any external libraries_" to "_not allowed to import any libraries_" which technically is changing the question and invalidates my answer.  I will allow the change to stand, but I've added the word "external" back into the question post, but formatted with strikethrough to indicate it was there, and is now removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how should i modify the range limits with the counter in order to improve efficiency?

Comment: Hint: If your binary sequence is 10 characters long, and you are looking for subsequences between 2 and 4 characters in length, what is the largest starting index you can possibly use?  How did you determine that?  What can you say about the ending index when you are at any given starting index.  Are there special cases you might have to worry about?  Do you have to handle them with separate code, or can you prevent them from occurring somehow?

Comment: I tried this: 

sequence_counts = Counter(sequence[i:i+j]
                          for i in range(n-shortest)
                          for j in range(shortest,longest+1))

But i get errors, how do i solve this?

Comment: You can post a followup question on Stack Overflow.  Code Review is for reviewing working code, improving efficiency, and helping identify previously unknown bugs.  We've pointed out the inefficiency, you've identified how it can be fixed, and now you've got a bug or error.  Include a link to this question for context, and add a link in this question to your followup question on Stack Overflow so reviewers can follow the progress.